# ajax jquery not working, not entering sucess

Tags: jquery

I have an html page that is trying to call the ajax jquery call below.  If I put the url in a browser, I get the data back.  The first alert works, showing we R IN.  The alert in the success never pops up, it goes to the error alert.  Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
        function GetAllStaff() {
        alert('we R IN');
    $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
        url:"http://MyServer/MyService/api/StaffSearch/GetAllStaff",

        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {

            alert('hello world');



        },
        error: function(msg) {

            alert('This is the error: ' + msg.d);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is the page running on a webserver or local? And what error is returned?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I'm running it locally, error says undefined

Comment: `data: "{}",` <-- this actually should look like this: `data: {},`

Comment: That is likely the problem. Upload it somewhere.

Comment: also is the content you are getting really json? if not then you will never get into the success part.

Comment: @ITroubs perhaps the server _wants_ an empty JSON object?

Comment: I changed "{}" to {}, still didn't work.  I had already tried that, just tried it again to double check.

Comment: if the server wants an empty json object it should look like that: `data: {passedData: "{}"},`

Comment: I tried data: {passedData: "{}"}  that didn't work either.

Comment: Try a `curl http://MyServer/MyService/api/StaffSearch/GetAllStaff -v` to see what the server sends as content type

Comment: and again: Is the page where the javascript is placed running locally (e.g. `file:///....`) or is the page on the same server or on a different server?

Comment: btw, when you just want to fetch a URL for json data, try the `getJSON()` method from jquery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: what does "http://MyServer/MyService/api/StaffSearch/GetAllStaff" return?

Comment: a list of staff, division, phone numbers, email

Comment: I used fiddler and verified the data is coming back as json

Answer (score 0):

It was a cross domain issue, I just added the line $.support.cors=true; and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the DATA line, and it should work.
A good way to find an ajax request problem is using FireBug.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
        url:"http://MyServer/MyService/api/StaffSearch/GetAllStaff",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {

            alert('hello world');
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            alert('This is the error: ' + msg.d);
        }
    });
```